# Elementary lower bound for solutions to the equation $a^{n}+b^{n}=c^{n}$

Tags: solution-verification, diophantine-equations

Let it be $a$, $b$ and $c$ some positive integers such that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are pairwise coprime, and such that

$$a^{n}+b^{n}=c^{n}$$

Let us assume that $a^{n}$ and $c^{n}$ are the odd numbers of the equation. Therefore, we can express that $b=2^{x}I$, where $2^{x}$ is the higher power of two dividing $b$ and $I$ is the remaining odd integer dividing $b$, and thus $b^{n}=2^{nx}I^{n}$.

Operating, we can state that

$$b^{n}=c^{n}-a^{n}$$

It can be seen that $2^{nx}$ must divide exactly the expression $c^{n}-a^{n}$.

By the binomial expansion, it can be noted that $c^{n}-a^{n}$ for $n\geq3$, $n$ odd, can be factored as $\left(c-a\right)\left(c^{n-1}+c^{n-2}a+...+ca^{n-2}+a^{n-1}\right)$, where the numbers of terms in the second parenthesis is odd; and thus, the sum inside the second parenthesis is odd.

As a result, the higher power of two dividing $c^{n}-a^{n}$ is the same as the higher power of two dividing $c-a$.

Therefore, it follows that necessarily $2^{nx}$ must divide exactly $c-a$.

It can be easily proved that, if $a^{n}+b^{n}=c^{n}$, then $c<a+b<2c$. Therefore, $c-a<b$.

As a result, we get that the equation $a^{n}+b^{n}=c^{n}$ can have solutions for $n$ being some odd prime number only for values of $b>2^{nx}$ (and thus, $c>2^{nx}$), $b$ having some odd factor $I>2^{n-1}$.

Is this lower bound rightly proved? Thanks!

Comment: I could not understand notation of $b=2^{x}I_{x}$. What is the $x$ in the index of $I_x$ ?

Comment: Well noted, the notation is misleading; I edit it

Comment: I've discussed that problem in more length & width in an essay in http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf After a presentation of a certain notation style there follow a couple of exercises, and in 3.11 I use the tools to look at the FLT-equation much in the case you do it here with primefactor $2$ but a bit more general. Possibly you'll like to see that treatize.

Comment: @Gottfried Helms really interesting essay, I will take a look at it; thanks for sharing!